# How do I describe the inner workings of my web app

Tags: php, ajax, database, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have designed a web app, this application contains not only some complex controllers, models and views but also some custom libraries and a database.

On top of this there is an ajax layer so: javascript functions and their related server side functions.

I've developed this app by myself and I want some way to ensure that 1 year down the line, if someone else picks it up there is some reference to the logic flow.

**Are there tools for this? Has anyone had this issue before?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good beginning would be to start using PHP Documentor (PHPDoc) before your code base gets too large. Even then, it's not too hard to go back and tag your classes, etc. PHPDoc will crawl the code base and produce documentation, typically a web-based (HTML) set of docs, but you can also produce PDF and more. The functions, methods, classes, etc. will have links to related elements of your code. I say before it gets too large, because you will want to go back and add comment tags to enhance the output of the documents. PHPDocumentor (PHPDoc) can be found here http://www.phpdoc.org/
, and information and tutorials can be found all over the web. If you have gone this far with PHP then surely you must have noticed comments like this...(doc blocks)

```
/**
 *@todo something I need to do
 *@param [type] [$varname] [description]
 *
 */
```

These tags/DocBlocks are to be parsed by PHPDoc, and are very useful...Most IDE's too are very friendly to using DocBlocks and will sometimes enhance code hinting, etc. based on the DocBlocks in your code.

For the Database...there are many tools and teqniques but here is one suggestion...

The database can be described by tools that will build diagrams. For instance, when using MySQL, you could install MySQL Workbench, and this will then give you the tools to connect to the database and build a diagram similar to the picture on this page...
http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Workbench, plus many other tools for reverse-enginerring and/or designing, tools for ORM, and more. Sometimes to just diagram and existing DB can be very useful especially when there are many relationships. MySQL Workbench will give you the option to send the diagram to PDF or an image. All very useful.

Not only will this help future developers, but these tools will help yourself too. We're all surprised to realize what we forget after a few weeks, months, etc. of not looking at the code. Even a busy weekend can make for a slow start again on Monday morning.

For my last suggestion...and I will be simple here, but look into bug/issue tracking. There are many online or you can install your own. Some go along with version control (like at GitHub, Unfuddle, BitBucket, etc.)...or you can install your own. I find Bugzilla is pretty easy to install if your using Ubuntu it's right in the repository and installs with ease.

Answer (score 1):

This surely isn't the whole answer you are looking for, but what I always find very useful is a proper documentation! And yes there are some really good tools like [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) for example. This does partly allow you to create a documentation of the workflow, at least to explain what exactly you are doing.

Further down the line you might just explain in plain english how it `flows`. If it is a really big application, you could even think of creating your own [wiki](http://www.wikispaces.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

This is generally known as "as-built" documentation; there's a wealth of information on the interwebs.

My preference is to split the documentation into several sections; each is as important as the other, but you don't need to spend equal amounts of time on them.

**Functional design**

What's the application supposed to do? What is expected behaviour? What are the key user journeys?

I like to use [use cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) or user stories for this, at varying levels of detail. A system context diagram also helps. Use cases can be both visual and textual; a couple of hours is often enough to describe a simple application

**Non-functional requirements**

Things like security, performance, browser support, SEO, accessibility - listing the things you have and have not accommodated in the application, so future developers know what to worry about and what to test for.

**Conceptual design**

A high-level overview of the system as built, identifying the major components, integration points, and dependencies.

**Detailed design**

This is the bit that is most subject to change, and the biggest pain to maintain. Using PHPDoc is a great way of keeping this up to date.

**Acceptance tests**

Even if you don't buy into Test-Driven Development, leaving future developments with ways of testing that the application works is a great way to keep them sane. Ideally, acceptance tests would be automated/scripted (e.g.using Selenium).

**Known bugs**

Providing a list of known bugs to future developers stops them from pulling out their hair...

All of this can be a lot of work - so many teams use "low-formality' ways of communicating - wikis, photos of whiteboards, even video with the team explaining the design.

More formally, there are standards like UML to help capture documentation in an industry standard way.